# JavaScript: property assignment through prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm struggling to understand the difference of the following 2 sets of code. The original code is from [the famous Ninja tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#66) and I have simplified a bit for myself.

**Question:** I think I understand how CodeA works. `Ninja.prototype.swung = false` is assigning a new property into `function Ninja()`, and `ninjiaA.swung` evaluates to false because of that. However, in CodeB, when we declare the `function Ninja()` with `this.swung = true` in the beginning, the later assignment of `Ninja.prototype.swung = false` does not take an effect, and `ninjaA.swung` remains to be evaluated to true. I'm failing to understand why this later assignment does not work in CodeB. Could somebody please enlighten me on this?

**CodeA:**

```
function Ninja(){}  
Ninja.prototype.swung = false; 
var ninjaA = new Ninja();
ninjaA.swung; //evaluates to false
```

**CodeB:**

```
function Ninja(){ 
  this.swung = true; 
}  
Ninja.prototype.swung = false; //I'm expecting this changes swung to false, 
                               //but it doesn't.
var ninjaA = new Ninja();      
ninjaA.swung; //evaluates to true
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you declare a property using `this` inside the constructor function, it gets attached to every object of that constructor.

When you declare a property on the prototype of that constructor function, it remains there and all objects of that constructor refer to it. When you have a property with the *same name* in the object and in the prototype chain, the object's property hides the one on the prototype.

Think how the property is evaluated in the prototype chain which might makes things clearer.

**CodeA:**

```
ninjaA.swung

1. Is swung a property of the current object - No
2. Is swung a property of the current object's prototype - Yes
    2.1. Return it
```

**CodeB:**

```
ninjaA.swung

1. Is swung a property of the current object? - Yes
    1.1 Return it
```

In code B, it never gets to the property on the prototype.

Comment: I edited your answer to use the `pre` tag. I find the almost humorous coloring to detract from the quality of the answer.

Comment: @Dan - thanks :) @ChaosPandion - thanks for the change, looks a lot better now :)

Answer (score 6):

When calling `Ninja` as a constructor you assign the value `true` to `swung`. Before the constructor is executed the object will look like this:

```
{
    prototype : {
        swung : false
    }
}
```

After the constructor is executed:

```
{
    prototype : {
        swung : false
    },
    swung : true
}
```

When you ask for the property `swung` the prototype chain will be checked at each level to see if it exists. If it doesn't exist the value `undefined` will be returned.

Comment: +1 your new additions make it very clear as to what's going on.

Comment: @Anurag - Thanks, I do think your step-by-step way of explaining it will help a novice understand it better though.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript the method appended to the prototype is only invoked if the method isn't found on the instance first.